# Drupal 7 - Create a custom template that can be assigned to different pages

Tags: 7, theming

I want to have a custom template for pages. WordPress has template selection feature for Pages or Posts. Is that possible for Drupal?

Comment: Which Drupal? 6/7 ?

Comment: Drupal 7, Here i want a single template assign to some of pages. like Wordpress have defalut page, showcase page, sidebar page.

Comment: Add 7 tag to your Question. Also see my answer.

Comment: Here i need, Suppose i create a Custom template name "page--twocolumn.tpl.php" and that template assign to some different pages. like node-7, node-8 and node-3 etc.

Comment: No Of course not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here [Drupal 7 Theme Hook Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)

For nodes You can use

```
    node--[type|nodeid].tpl.php
    base template: node.tpl.php
    Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors, 
listed from the most specific template to the least. 
Drupal will use the most specific template it finds:

    node--nodeid.tpl.php
    node--type.tpl.php
    node.tpl.php
```

Also [Drupal 6 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089642)

To use same tpl for multiple pages you need to use `theme_preprocess_node`
Like

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  if(in_array($node->nid), $myuids)
   $vars['template_file'] = 'your_template_file';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Panelizer](https://drupal.org/project/panelizer). It allows you to use [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) for content types, and you can define different layouts, content, contexts, etc. on a per node basis.

In my opinion, this approach is much easier to maintain than having a bunch of separate template files in your theme.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a MYMODULE module;

Put the following code:

```
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $theme = array();
  $theme['TEST_NAME'] = array(
    'template' => 'TEMPLATE-NAME',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE'),
  );
  return $theme;
}
```

2. Create a file TEMPLATE-NAME.tpl.php in the module folder;
3. Output it in places you wish with the code:

   ```
   theme('TEST_NAME', $vars);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Take also a look at the [Theme Guide](http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7) and the [Core templates](http://drupal.org/node/190815).